# Accessing Result property of a Task

Tags: c#, facebook, task-parallel-library, facebook-c#-sdk

I am trying to retrieve the ID of an album using the C# Facebook SDK. However I am getting the below error:

> System.Threading.Tasks.Task' does not contain a definition for 'Result' and no extension method 'Result' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' could be found

Please see the below code, the error occurs on the foreach line

```
try
{
    string wallAlbumID = string.Empty;
    FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
    client.GetTaskAsync(pageID + "/albums")
        .ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                if (!task.IsFaulted)
                {
                    foreach (dynamic album in task.Result.data)
                    {
                        if (album["type"] == "wall")
                        {
                            wallAlbumID = album["id"].ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new DataRetrievalException("Failed to retrieve wall album ID.", task.Exception.InnerException);
                }
            });
    return wallAlbumID;
}
```

For the record, the `FacebookClient.GetTaskAsync` method returns `Task<object>`

Comment: If you debug the code and look at the runtime type of "task", you may find it is a derivative of the Task type, and you may just need to do a cast, e.g. `((SomeFacebookTaskType)task).Result`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I compile your code, I get two errors, the first one is the one you mentioned, and the second one is:

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'data' and no extension method 'data' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found

This second error is your actual error: `task.Result` is an `object`, but (I assume) you want to treat it as `dynamic`. Because of this error, the compiler also tries to use the overload of `ContinueWith()` that uses just `Task`, not `Task<object>`, which is why you're *also* getting the first error.

To fix this error, you should cast `task.Result` to `dynamic`:

```
dynamic result = task.Result;
foreach (dynamic album in result.data)
```

This will compile fine, but it won't actually work, because you set the local variable after you return from the enclosing method.

If you're using C# 5.0, you should use `await` here, instead of `ContinueWith()`:

```
try
{
    dynamic result = await client.GetTaskAsync(pageID + "/albums");
    foreach (dynamic album in result.data)
    {
        if (album["type"] == "wall")
        {
            return (string)album["id"].ToString();
        }
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
catch (Exception e) // you should use a specific exception here, but I'm not sure which
{
    throw new DataRetrievalException("Failed to retrieve wall album ID.", e);
}
```

If you can't use C# 5.0, then your whole method should return a `Task<string>` that's returned by `ContinueWith()`:

```
return client.GetTaskAsync(pageID + "/albums")
      .ContinueWith(
          task =>
          {
              if (!task.IsFaulted)
              {
                  dynamic result = task.Result;
                  foreach (dynamic album in result.data)
                  {
                      if (album["type"] == "wall")
                      {
                          return (string)album["id"].ToString();
                      }
                  }
                  return string.Empty;
              }
              else
              {
                  throw new DataRetrievalException(
                      "Failed to retrieve wall album ID.", task.Exception.InnerException);
              }
          });
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the Facebook API, but the error seems to indicate, that you're dealing with [`Task` class (non-generic) which does not have `Result` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx). It is [the generic `Task<T>` derived from non-generic `Task` class that has the property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424.aspx). They both allow to run code asynchronously, but the generic class is able to run methods that return values.

If `GetTaskAsync` returns `Task` and not `Task<T>`, then it means you can't get the result from it, as the operation it runs in the background does not return anything.

Comment: Actually, the error message suggest this, but it's not actually true.

Comment: I also cannot access the Result property of a Task that I know for a fact is of the derived type Task<T> using the dynamic keyword. The error message seems to indicate it's of type Task, but that is 100% false, because the runtime type is Task<T>.